# MongoDB: Indexes, Sorting

Tags: mongodb

After having read the official documentations on indexes, sort, intersection, i'm a little bit confuse on how everything work together.

I've trouble making my query use the indexes i've created. I work on a mongodb 3.0.3, on a collection having ~4millions of document.

To simplify, let's say my document is composed of 6 fields:

```
{
  a:<text>,
  b:<boolean>,
  c:<text>,
  d:<boolean>,
  e:<date>,
  f:<date>
}
```

The query I want to achieve is the following :

```
db.mycoll.find({ a:"OK", b:true, c:"ProviderA", d:true, e:{ $gte:ISODate("2016-10-28T12:00:01Z"),$lt:ISODate("2016-10-28T12:00:02") } }).sort({f:1});
```

So intuitively I've created two indexes

```
db.mycoll.createIndex({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d:1, e:1  }, {background: true,name: "test1"})
db.mycoll.createIndex({f:1}, {background: true,name: "test2"})
```

But the explain() give me that the first index is not used at all.
I known there is some kind of limitation when there is ranges in play in the filter (in the e field), but I can't find my way around it.

Also instead of having a single index on f, I try a compound index on {e:1,f:1} but it didn't change anything.

So What I have misunderstood?
Thanks for your support.

**Update:** also I find some time the following predicate for mongodb 2.6 :

> A good rule of thumb for queries with sort is to order the indexed fields in this order:
>
> - First, the field(s) on which you will query for exact values.
> - Second, the field(s) on which you will sort.
> - Finally, field(s) on which you will query for a range of values (e.g., $gt, $lt, $in)

An example of using this rule of thumb is in the section on “Sorting the results of a complex query on a range of values” below, including a link to further reading.

Does this also apply for 3.X version?

**Update 2:** following above predicate, I created the following index

```
db.mycoll.createIndex({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d:1 , f:1, e:1}, {background: true,name: "test1"})
```

And for the same query :

```
db.mycoll.find({ a:"OK", b:true, c:"ProviderA", d:true, e:{ $gte:ISODate("2016-10-28T12:00:01Z"),$lt:ISODate("2016-10-28T12:00:02") } }).sort({f:1});
```

the index is indeed used. However too much keys seems to be scan, I may need to find a better order the fields in the query/index.

Comment: I believe as per mongo explanation , If the query does not specify an equality condition on an index prefix that precedes or overlaps with the sort specification, the operation will not efficiently use the index and may not even use the index to retrieve the documents

Answer (score 1):

Mongo acts sometimes a bit strange when it comes to the index selection.

Mongo automagically decides what index to use. The smaller an index is the more likely it is used (especially indexes with only one field) - this is my experience. May be this happens because it is more often already loaded in RAM? To find out what index to use when Mongo performs test queries when it is idle. However the result is sometimes unexpected.

Therefore if you know what index to use you can force a query to use a specific index using the [`$hint`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) option. You should try that.

Comment: I know I can use the `$hint` operator,  but if I can avoid to use this, its better.

Answer (score 1):

Your two indexes used in the query and the sort does not overlap so MongoDB [can not use them for index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort):

> Index intersection does not apply when the `sort()` operation requires an index completely separate from the query predicate.

Comment: whould it be better if I was to create an index like :

`db.mycoll.createIndex({e:1, f:1}, {background: true,name: "test3"})`